# Datatable: Skipping empty entries while sorting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting, datatable

i am trying to sort email column in data-table while skipping the empty entries , Below is the code snippet. I have added this code after Datatable js files .

```
    <script>

        jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "non-empty-string-asc": function (str1, str2) {
            if(str1 == "")
                return 1;
            if(str2 == "")
                return -1;
            return ((str1 < str2) ? -1 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : 0));
        },

        "non-empty-string-desc": function (str1, str2) {
            if(str1 == "")
                return 1;
            if(str2 == "")
                return -1;
            return ((str1 < str2) ? 1 : ((str1 > str2) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    } );


    var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        columnDefs: [
           {type: 'non-empty-string', targets: ['email']} // define 'name' column as non-empty-string type
        ]
    });

</script>
```

below are my column names

```
$columns = array(
     array( 'db' => 'country',  'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'city',   'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'name',     'dt' => 2 ),

    array( 'db' => 'contact1', 'dt' => 3),
    array( 'db' => 'contac2',  'dt' => 4 ),
     array( 'db' => 'email',     'dt' => 5),
    array( 'db' => 'project', 'dt' => 6 ),
    array( 'db' => 'national',  'dt' => 7),
    array( 'db' => 'developer',   'dt' => 8 ),

);
```

Above code is not sorting the required issue tried to pass index as well but that did not work , please advise.

Comment: You mean no sorting happens at all, or it doesn't happen in the order you want? Browser console has anything to say? _"below are my column names"_ - not really that helpful, you'd need to show us what you are actually _making_ out of that data.

Comment: once data is sorted i want empty rows to go at the end at the mmoment its showing them in start or in the middle when sorting

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be wrong for empty string cases.

As per my understanding you want to push all empty to end both in asc and desc.

but in your logic you are passing 1 and -1 whihc will behave same was as other string.

Your code should be like this

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "non-empty-string-asc": function (str1, str2) {
        if(str1 == "" || str2 == "")
            return -1; // pushes to last 
        return ((str1 < str2) ? -1 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "non-empty-string-desc": function (str1, str2) {
        if(str1 == "" || str2 == "")
            return -1; // pushes to last 
        return ((str1 < str2) ? 1 : ((str1 > str2) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```